# Compose the correct output for dict JSON

Tags: python, json

I am writing a parser for ads, I ran into a problem that the dict is not displayed in full, but only the first part.

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

url = 'https://api.yo.com/api/v1/products?app_id=web2'

response = requests.get(url).json()

items = response['data']
iter1 = []
for item in items:
   iter1.append({
     'name': item.get('name', 'NA'),
     'owner': item.get('owner', 'NA'),
     'date_published': item.get('date_published', 'NA'),
     'short_url': item.get('short_url', 'NA')
   })

result = {}
for keyvalue in iter1:
    result["name"] = iter1[0]["name"]
    result["user"] = iter1[1]["owner"]["name"]
    result["date_published"] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(iter1[0]["date_published"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    result["short_url"] = iter1[0]["short_url"]
print(keyvalue)
```

Output example print(keyvalue):

```
{'name': 'text ads', 'user': 'John. Doe', 'date_published': '2021-08-02 20:37:13', 'short_url': 'https://yo.com/p610009e'}
```

What is actually contained in iter1:

```
[{'name': 'IPhone 7 32 gb', 'owner': {'id': '5a552f202d23c1214'}, 'date_published': 1627937371, 'short_url': 'https://yo/p60ff'}, 
{'name': 'Матрас, подушка', 'owner': {'id': '5dc2590dabc73388f2', 'name': 'Olga', 'type': 'b2b_professional', 'linked_id': '5dc2590dad53388f2', 'is_shop': False, 'is_verified': False, 'image': {'id': '5dc2756ba162b6342', 'num': 1, 'url': 'https://cach6342.jpg'}, 'date_registered': 1573017904, 'settings': {'display_phone_to_anon': True, 'display_phone': True, 'display_chat': True, 'location': {'description': 'Москва'}}, 'display_phone_num': None, 'isOnline': False, 'onlineText': 'Не в сети', 'online_text_detailed': 'Сегодня в 23:30', 'answerTimeText': '', 'is_blocked': False, 'store': None, 'rating_mark': 4.4}, 'date_published': 1627542263, 'short_url': 'https://yo/p60dac06897'}, 
{'name': 'Букеты', 'owner': {'id': '59d60973a3f3386f3f', 'name': 'Екатерина', 'type': 'person', 'linked_id': '59d609739e9486f3f', 'is_shop': False, 'is_verified': False, 'image': {'id': '59db3e1457556c13', 'num': 1, 'url': 'https://cac/i/oi/d6/59d609b.jpg'}, 'date_registered': 1507199347, 'settings': {'display_phone_to_anon': False, 'display_phone': False, 'display_chat': True}, 'display_phone_num': None, 'isOnline': False, 'onlineText': 'Не в сети', 'online_text_detailed': 'Сегодня в 21:44', 'answerTimeText': '', 'is_blocked': False, 'store': None, 'rating_mark': 0}, 'date_published': 1627472412, 'short_url': 'https://you/p60a0db5de263'}]
```

How can I display all the lines 'print(keyvalue)' that are processed in result = {}?

Comment: You need to update your question because right now it is not clear what the end goal is. The `keyvalue` is only displaying one result because you keep overwriting it in the for loop. If you want to keep all the values from `iter1` you will need some sort of dict also in `result` variable.

Comment: Just put the print(keyvlue) into the loop and you will get similar output if that is what you want as I understood. It wont be a list of dicts but a print-out of particular dicts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got yourself confused about how iteration works in python. But its interesting how your first loop is fine: `for item in items:`

You probably meant this for your second loop:

```py
output = []
for result in iter1:
    item = {}
    item["name"] = result["name"]
    item["user"] = result["owner"].get("name")
    date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(result["date_published"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    item["date_published"] = date
    item["short_url"] = result["short_url"]
    output.append(item)
print(output)
```

You could probably collapse the two loops into one, but best to start with two.